# VBA Rows.count and FormulaR1C1

Tags: vba, excel

I've got some VBA scirpt in excel that copies unique values from Column A, to column E then should total values from column B into column F for each.  I found the snippet below online and have been editing it to fit my spreadsheet.

Original snippet that works in the example workbook to copy values from column B to column K and sums column I into column L.

```
Columns("B:B").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CriteriaRange:=Columns( _
    "B:B"), CopyToRange:=Range("'Example1'!K1"), Unique:=True

   For i = 2 To Cells(Rows.Count, 11).End(xlUp).Row
   Cells(i, "L").FormulaR1C1 = "=SUMIF(C[-10],RC[-1],C[-3])"
   Next i
```

My edited code that does copy the unique value from A into E, but does not perform the sum:

```
Range("A5:A30").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CopyToRange:=Range("'Sheet1'!E7"), Unique:=True

   For i = 2 To Cells(Rows.Count, 11).End(xlUp).Row
   Cells(i, "F6").FormulaR1C1 = "=SUMIF(C[-4],RC[-1],C[-4])"
   Next i
```

The part I think is wrong is the

```
For i =  2 To Cells(Rows.Count, 11).End(x1Up).Row
```

but I'm sure sure the meaning of this line, especially where it has 11.  Anyone have any idea why this isn't working?

@Jarom
Edit:  My spreadsheet looks like this when I run the edited code, its not totaling properly and giving 0 value.

```
{Part        Quantity   Order Number  Part      Needed  Scanned 
6116022-42ID    28        041981                        
6116022-42ID    13        041981    Part Number     0       
6116126-01      42        041981    6116022-42ID    0       
6116784-15      42        041981    6116126-01      0       
6116022-42ID    1         041981    6116784-15      0       }
```

Comment: `x1Up` should be `xlUp` it is a lower case `L` not the number `1`.

Comment: The `11` is the column number.

Comment: and I believe that you want `6` instead of `"F6"` in the next line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `cells` function references a cell based on row and column numbers like this `cells(row reference,column reference)`.  So `cells(1,2)` references the cell `B1`.

It does look like the problem is in your loop.  With a `for` loop you run an operation a certain amount of times based on the number of a variable.
The first line identifies how many iterations of the loop it will do.  `i` is the variable the sets the loop.  `i` starts at 7 and goes to `cells(7,5).end(xldown).Rows`.  The `cells(7,5).end(xldown).Rows` code goes to cell E7 and gets the row number of the bottom of the group of populated cells (it does the equivalent of the ctrl + down arrow and gets the row number).  That way the loop iterates starting at cell E7 and goes to the lowest of the populated group cells in the column E. Notice that the code in the loop has a reference to `i` in the row part of the `cells` function.  `i` increases with every iteration of the loop, so the input to the `cells` function increases every loop, which is how the loop goes down one row for every iteration.

```
Sub test()

Range("A5:A30").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CopyToRange:=Range("'Sheet1'!E7"), Unique:=True

For i = 7 To Cells(7, 5).End(xlDown).Row
      Cells(i, 6).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIf(Range("A:A"), Cells(i, 5),Range("B:B"))
Next i


End Sub
```

I hope that this helps you understand what the code is doing.

Comment: I understand the command better now, thank you!  The code you posted doesn't work for this either though.  My actual data that needs copied and totaled begins row 6.  because advanced filter thinks there is a header row, I began the script at row 5 to copy the header row instead of duplicating the data.

Comment: So are you saying that you just need to include row 6 in the loop?  If so, you just change `i = 7` to `i = 6`

Comment: Also, see that I made an edit to update the formula in the loop.

Comment: Sorry for the delay of the weekend.  It isn't placing a total from column B into Column F for each unique row (part number) from column A.

Comment: Did you put the edit I made in your code?  Using `application.formula` instead of `formular1c1` Just want to make sure before I explore other things.

Comment: Yes I did, it didn't put any sum in column F.

Comment: Oh, I think I found it.  Change `.rows` to `.row` in the first line of the loop.  I'll edit the post.  Let me know if that works.

Comment: I edited my main post to show you how the spreadsheet looks after the code runs, it isn't totalling, just giving 0 for each unique part.

Comment: Oh ok, I see now.  That was my mistake.  I needed to add the condition range of A:A.  See the edited code now.

Comment: Awesome, glad to hear it!  Sorry it took a little while to get there.  If you don't mind accepting the answer if you are happy with your code now.

Comment: I did, but I don't have a score of 15 so it doesn't count - I clicked the check mark just now, I had done the up arrow on your answer thinking that did it.